# Alternative to KDE screenshots on Windows

Tags: screenshot

At home I use KDE, and take screenshots with printscreen button, a window popsup, I can select whether I want to screenshot only an active window, or a fullscreen, or a custom rectangle, etc. Then I can Copy/Paste the screenshot, or upload it or save it.

Is there something like that on Windows? Preferably open source.

Comment: It is a built-in function of Windows.  Why do you want something different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the "Snipping Tool" - comes in Windows 10.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13776/windows-10-use-snipping-tool-to-capture-screenshots

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice before that you can choose how to printscreen the window(s) and copy the image to clipboard from the tool itself. Still, easy sharing/uploading to imgur/etc is not here, as is on KDE.